# Compilation error, Delphi project within Jenkins

Tags: android, delphi, jenkins, compilation, firemonkey

I migrated a project from Delphi 10.1 to Delphi 11 and when compiling the project, I get the error:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 /Users/jenkins/Jenkins/tools/android-ndk-r18b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:529: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)''
```

What could i be doing wrong?

I already created a new project, and imported the units, but even so the error continues...

Comment: That is a C++ linker error, why would you be getting that in a Delphi project?

Comment: I have no idea, I simply command it to compile and it brings this error.